# How is data class different from class with no body?

Tags: class, kotlin, oop, data-class

I just found out that the body and the header in the kotlin classes are optional. This means we can declare classes like this:-

```
class Contact(val id: Int, var email: String)
```

But doesn't it seems similar to the data class declaration. So why data classes is needed if we can use normal class for storing data?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html

Answer (score 4):

[Data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) (explicitly declared with a `data` keyword) have a bunch of desirable auto-generated methods that you would generally want for classes that store data:

- Consistent `equals`/`hashCode` using all properties declared in the constructor, so that the `==` operator is meaningful
- A useful `toString()` showing all properties and their values
- `componentN()` functions to allow destructuring
- `copy()` function for copying instances and optionally change a subset of the properties

Also, it seems from your question's title that you believe `data class`es cannot have members in their body - this is a misconception, they can.

However, it's important to note that every extra property that you declare in the body but not in the constructor will not be part of the generated methods (for instance they will not count in `equals()`).